# Are there risks or negative consequences in backgrounding a reboot call?

Tags: linux, shell-script, reboot

I'm writing some shell scripts designed to monitor and take corrective action(s) on high reliability Linux systems (kernal 5.0.19). One of these actions is to reboot the system in certain situations.

The way I have my reboot code written, I background the `/sbin/reboot now &` call to begin doing some other things in the code immediately after. I'm concerned this backgrounding may have implications I don't fully understand though. Googling around has given me no real information about this. Could anyone provide any knowledge or input on whether or not backgrounding a reboot or shutdown command in Linux is a good or bad decision?

**Additional Details**
From directives stipulated above me, this reboot process I write must:

1. Attempt a normal, safe reboot
2. Hard reset the system in the event the reboot hangs
3. Ensure as much data in memory is written to disk as possible in the event the hard reset is triggered.

The hard reset of the system is triggered thanks to a hardware watchdog circuit soldered onto the system which causes every (~99.9%) reboot to act as a hard reset + the [software watchdog daemon](https://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog) process. Killing the watchdog process triggers a 60s countdown after which a hard reset will occur.

**The way my code is written we:**

1. Kill the watchdog process, begin the hard reset countdown
2. **Attempt a normal reboot and background the process `/sbin/reboot now &`**
3. Begin syncing constantly assuming the `reboot` command hangs

Here's the relevant snippet from my reboot function:

```bash
# Kill watchdog daemon process(es), this starts 60s countdown to hard reset
pkill -9 watchdog
if (( $? == 0 )); then
    logThis INFO "Watchdog processes killed successfully, creatinged \"$watchdogTriggeredFile\""
    touch $watchdogTriggeredFile
fi

# Attempt a normal reboot before the watchdog forces ember to reboot
/sbin/reboot now &
# In testing, anytime the watchdog forces a reboot we lose ~15-25  
# seconds of logs. This is due to log writes being stored in memory. 
# The watchdog process does not call sync before it kills power to the
# system, so anything stored in memory is lost, therefore:
# Constantly write memory to disk until watchdog triggers reboot (60s)
for (( n=0; n<=600; n+=2)); do
    # Watchdog forces reboot after 60s, we sleep every .2, 60 / .2 = 300 iterations
    # Can't do floating point arithmetic in bash so we use 600 / 2 = 300 instead 
    # 300 iterations is more than 60s due to context switching and execution time
    sync    
    sleep 0.2
done
```

So, in the code above, does it seem like there may be any major issues with backgrounding that `reboot now` call so I can move on to attempting syncs?

Comment: My gut feeling is that you'd want **one** `sync` before you start the reboot, because that will trigger the writing of the outstanding logs. The 299 or so syncs after will not be desirable, because they make your shutdown process, which doesn't seem to be so unlikely to succeed under normal circumstances, unnecessarily slow.

Comment: It's a good thought, I originally had it that way. Just a single `sync` after the `reboot now` call. What I found in testing though is that additional log messages after that `sync` command would be lost. This was easy to test as there's a `watchdog timer expired!` log message immediately before reboot that appears on console but is never there after reboot (unless multiple sync calls). Management wants every possible log message, so the question became, how can I ensure the maximum amount of log messages? Best case would be a `sync` just before the reboot but a long `sleep 55` was veto'd.